# error MSB4181: The "Re solveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, gitlab, msbuild

As I am building my application in `gitlab.Applicati`on source code is in `.NET` and it is giving me an error and warnings.

**Exception:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2977,5): error MSB4181: The "ResolveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error. [C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\3izCYubi\0\dhanlaxmi-applications\stormapp\ProjectHO\ProjectHO.csproj]
    40 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:06.33
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

The command I have used to build the .NETapplication using msbuild tool:

```
$ cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MsBuild"
$ MsBuild.exe "C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\3izCYubi\0\dhanlaxmi-applications\stormapp\Live_Prjct.sln"
```

Any hint on how I can solve this problem would be helpful.

Comment: Is ProjectHO.csproj targeting .NET Framework or .NET (aka .NET Core)?

Comment: Hello @JonathanDodds
Its .NET Framework

Comment: The `ResolveComReference` task needs to be able to find the `AxImp.exe` and `TlbImp.exe` tools. I can see from the path in the error message that you have "Build Tools for VS2022" installed. Instead of changing directory, run the `VsDevCmd.bat` batch file to modify the environment and PATH for the VS2022 tools. The install of the "Build Tools" may have added a start menu shortcut item for a "Developer Command Prompt". Check the shortcut for the batch file path. (The batch file is probably at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat". )

Comment: I have run the VsDevCmd.bat batch file and after that, I tried to build my project by using the msbuild .sln file. but after doing this I am facing the same issue as earlier.

Comment: Are you using a batch file with both commands or a one-line command like `VsDevCmd.bat & msbuild`? If you enable a higher level of logging verbosity (e.g. `msbuild -v:detailed ...`), is there more detail relevant to the error?

Comment: I have tried both commands on the CLI but not working. In GitLab we are using the following command to build the .sln file

MsBuild.exe "C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\3izCYubi\0\dhanlaxmi-applications\stormapp\Live_Prjct.sln"

Answer (score 0):

Are there any issues with your package reference?
According to the official documentation, you can run msbuild with -`verbosity:diag` commandline to get more detailed error information.
If there is a more detailed error message, I can help you better.

Reference documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb4181?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem today and my issue was:
`$env:BuildType`

I have multiple pipeline options that all use `$BuildType` to pick up the correct build to run, and also use VS2022 BuildTools.
Only my Reporting Services pipeline build kept giving the same error MSB4181.

Changing my pipeline `$BuildType` to another variable name now runs correctly.

Found this by running the same commands on the build server without the $env variables which completes the build without errors and then referencing between the 2 `-verbosity:diag` outputs.